# How to make translate animation slower by half on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried various avenues to replicate the animation on this page

https://www.apple.com/services/

As you see, there are looping carousels consisting of thumbnails that move to the left (translateX). When you hover on them, their speed is slowed down by about half. This looks simple, but it turns out to be one of the most complex tasks I tried to achieve. I've tried.

```
.carousel {
animation-name: move-to-right 
animation-duration: 5s;
}

.carousel:hover {
animation-duration: 10s;
}
```

it slows down the animation, but on mouse out, the carousels jump to the left. Pausing the animation on hover is very simple, but slowing it down, can't find the correct way to do that.

Comment: The example you are referring to does not appear to be using `animation`; the movement is achieved via `transform: matrix(...)` set as inline style, with the actual values calculated by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [Web Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) you can control the [`playbackRate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/playbackRate) of any animation (CSS `animation` or `transition` or Web `Animation`):

```js
document.querySelector(".carousel").onmouseenter = (evt) => {
  const anim = evt.currentTarget.getAnimations()
    .find(({ animationName }) => animationName === "move-to-right");
  if (!anim) { return; }
  anim.playbackRate = 0.5;
};

document.querySelector(".carousel").onmouseleave = (evt) => {
  const anim = evt.currentTarget.getAnimations()
    .find(({ animationName }) => animationName === "move-to-right");
  if (!anim) { return; }
  anim.playbackRate = 1;
};
```

```css
.carousel {
  width: 600vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue, red);
  background: linear-gradient(to right in hsl longer hue, red, blue, red);
  background-size: 500vw 100%;
  animation: move-to-right 2.5s infinite linear;
}
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: clip;
}
  
@keyframes move-to-right {
  to {
    translate: -500vw 0;
  }
}
```

```html
Mouse over to slow down.<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: Your web animation API reference has provided me with a fresh perspective on how to approach animations, particularly in my own work. Thank you.

Comment: @RobithNurielHaq yes, I honestly have trouble understanding how this API hasn't gathered more love across the years. It's relatively intuitive and far more performant than any other solutions. There is almost no reasons to trigger CSS transitions or animations through DOM manipulation anymore, that gives us direct access to the actual Animation that the CSS will generate.